# Android smartphone as opencl usb compute device?

Tags: driver, opencl, linux-device-driver

Is it possible to use android smartphone with opencl capability as usb plugged compute device?
So I just plug it in and it automatically seen from opencl program, no need for any setups.

tried google search, found nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not readily possible. Some smartphones do support OpenCL, but the ARM GPU device is not available as remote device to a connected PC.

Keep an eye out for [PoCL-Remote](https://youtu.be/Usj0CPC8zEs) though. This allows listing OpenCL devices from other computers on the network as local devices.